# Testing Ionic with Jasmine and Karma - Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

Long story short, when I run `karma.conf.js` I see `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined`

I am starting to work with a pre-existing Ionic project.. and add some unit tests.  Do I need to check our `www/index.html` .. I do not see `angular.js` included strangely enough.. is this the reason?

This team uses maven to build so I'm worried we're out of step with the rest of the community as far as building goes.

Update 1: adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/angular/angular.js"></script>` at the top of `www/index.html`'s includes has no effect.

Update 2: `index.html` contains ionic bundle
`<script src="lib/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>`

*Karma.conf.js*

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'www/lib/js/angular/angular.js',
    'www/lib/js/angular/angular-animate.js',
    'www/lib/js/angular/angular-animate.js',
    'www/lib/js/angular/angular-mocks.js',
    'www/lib/js/angular/angular-resource.js',
    'www/lib/js/angular/angular-sanitize.js',
    'www/lib/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.js',
    'www/lib/js/ionic.js',
    'www/lib/js/ionic-angular.js',
    'www/js/**/*.js',
    'www/test/jasmine/*.js'
],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ionic has Angular already, so you don't need to add Angular externally. You should probably remove `<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/angular/angular.js"></script>`

and make sure you are adding Ionic in your dependencies

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
```

And: remember to do this in your `index.html`

```
<body ng-app="myApp"></body>
```

*Could be in `body` tag or `html` tag, just make sure you are adding it.

**EDIT**

as @PSL says: Ionic Bundle has Angular in it. So I guess, you should to start using Ionic Bundle and stop worrying about it.

In case you are not using Ionic Bundle, add the reference for Angular in your Index, and make the declarations I mentioned above.

your karma file should look like this

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
    //Angular source
    'lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js',
    'lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'lib/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js',
    'lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js',
    'lib/ionic/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.js',
    'lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
    'lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',

    //App code
    'js/*.js',
    'js/controllers/*.js',
    'js/services/*.js',

    //Test files
    'test/controllers/*.js'
    ],
```

in case that you are not using some of the files above, just remove it from the array `files: []`

Comment: @PSL so he should be using ionic bundle to stop worrying about it.

Comment: Yeah that is possible... Probably you may want to reword `Ionic has Angular already, so you don't need to add Angular externally` ?

Comment: okay I removed the `angular.js` reference again from `index.html`

`index.html` looks good.
`angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])` looks good..

Comment: Added an update on ionic bundle to original post.  could this be due to adding `angular.js` explicitly in my `karma.conf.js` in addition to `ionic.js` ??

Comment: Just see your update. So you are using Ionic bundle, you should remove angular from Index. And yes, that might be a reason. Also remove that Angular reference from there, while you are referencing ionic bundle, you don't need anything regarding Angular main library.

Comment: @Erik, see my last update of how your karma file should look like.

Comment: Thanks, It's now complaining about my own dependencies instead of angular.  Progress!  Great tip on the ionic bundle too, had no idea.